# Google map editor api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, mapping

I am currently working on a project which needs an editor for google map so that users can draw polygons , lines , add markers , images, etc. Directly working with google map api is pain in the ... i am not satisfied and running out of time

Did you know any good apis to work with? I found some like [Google Maps API For .Net](http://googlemap.artembg.com/),  but it has several known bugs. Is there any javascript+jquery , flash , flex , or .net api to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for the drawing library included in version 3.7 of the maps API. Google is now providing this API as an add on library